# Why are the default DateTime values dropped when migrating using EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am currently using EF Core 6.0.15 and had been using EF 5 previously on the same code base meaning that I was able to perform migrations without seeing the current problem.

I have the following models (only showing one DateTime property to keep focus):

```
public class DistributionStatus
{
  public DateTime ApproxDownloadedDateTime{ get; set; }
}

public class IsdIndex
{
  public DateTime IoTCloudDeprecationDateTime{ get; set; }
}
```

and I don't have Data Annotations on either property.

Here is the dB before migration:

[image: State before migration]

which shows that there is a default value of `-infinity` for both DateTime properties.

Now, even though there are no changes in *any* of my Models, when I create the migration, I get:

```
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "ApproxDownloadedDateTime",
                table: "DistributionStatuses",
                type: "timestamp with time zone",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
                oldType: "timestamp with time zone",
                oldDefaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

This for me raises 2 questions, which I hope I can get clarity on:

1. Why is this code created to drop the default DateTime value for table `DistributionStatuses`?
2. Why is the same code not happening for table `IsdIndex`?

Moreover, in my model context, I am *not* setting default values for these tables.